# JQuery animate works only once on switch case

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my jquery. Please check my code below:

```
switch(i){
    case 1:
        $('#wrapper').animate({top: "0vh"},800,function(){
        console.log("done with 1");
    break;
    });

    case 2:
        $('#wrapper').animate({top: "-100vh"},800,function(){
        console.log("done with 2");
    break;
    });

}
```

Case 2 works which animates the top position of the wrapper. Now when case 1 is true, the wrapper's top position should go back to `0vh`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Create a JsFiddle that reproduces the issue, so we could help you easily

Comment: Running this switch gives a syntax error, please indent your code and you will spot a problem instantly.

Comment: the break statement, look where it is and where it should be

Answer (score 0):

Your `break;` is inside the `aminate()` callback function, instead of outside it. Fix your code and it will work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement contains a syntax error that prevents the code from executing.

```
switch(i) {
    case 1:
        $('#wrapper').animate({top: "0vh"},800,function(){
            console.log("done with 1");
        });
    break;

    case 2:
        $('#wrapper').animate({top: "-100vh"},800,function(){
            console.log("done with 2");
        });
    break;
}
```